# how to animate drop of MKAnnotationView with custom image

Tags: ios, swift3, mapkit, mkannotation

when I try to access the animate drop property of an MKAnnotationView, it doesn't exist. I know this property exists for a MKPinAnnotationView, but I'm using a custom image and therefore have to use a MKAnnotationView. Any way to animate the drop of a MKAnnotationView? Code:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation { return nil }

    var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: pinIdentifier)
    if annotationView == nil {
        annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: pinIdentifier)
        annotationView?.canShowCallout = true

        let pinImage = UIImage(named:"mappin")!
        annotationView?.image = pinImage
        //annotationView?.animatesDrop = true

    } else {
        annotationView?.annotation = annotation
    }
    return annotationView
}
```

Comment: did my answer help you?

Answer (score 2):

**1)** Create a `xib` file and an associated `.swift` file to hold your AnimatedAnnotation code.

[image: pics]

**2)** in `AnimatedAnnotation.xib` you can put your UI creativity to task and create your annotation.

[image]

**3)** In your `AnimatedAnnotation.swift` file, create your own `AnimatedAnnotation` class.

```
class AnimatedAnnotation: MKAnnotationView {


}
```

**4)** Next, write a configuration method that will configure an instance of this "invisible" container view with an `animationDuration`, and `annotationImage` (this will be your custom image).

```
class AnimatedAnnotation: UIView {

    var animationDuration: Double!
    var annotationImage: UIImage!

    func configureWith(animationDuration: Double, annotationImage: UIImage) {
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.annotationImage = annotationImage
        self.animationDuration = animationDuration
    }
}
```

**5)** Then declare a property `animatedView` of type `UIImageView` and instantiate it within your configuration block.

```
class AnimatedAnnotation: UIView {

    var animatedView: UIImageView!
    var animationDuration: Double!
    var annotationImage: UIImage!

    func configureWith(animationDuration: Double, annotationImage: UIImage) {
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.annotationImage = annotationImage
        self.animationDuration = animationDuration
        instantiateAnimatedView()
    }

    func instantiateAnimatedView() {
        let startingPosition = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20) // This is whatever starting position you want
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: startingPosition)
        imageView.image = UIImage(name: "YourAnnotationImage")
        imageView.alpha = 0
        addSubview(imageView!)
    }
}
```

**6)** Write the method to make the animated view appear and animate on top of it's "invisible" superview.

```
class AnimatedAnnotation: UIView {

    var animatedView: UIImageView!
    var animationDuration: Double!
    var annotationImage: UIImage!

    func configureWith(animationDuration: Double, annotationImage: UIImage) {
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.annotationImage = annotationImage
        self.animationDuration = animationDuration
        instantiateAnimatedView()
        dropAnnotation() // Call whenever you want the drop to happen
    }

    func instantiateAnimatedView() {
        let startingPosition = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20) // This is whatever starting position you want
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: startingPosition)
        imageView.image = annotationImage
        imageView.alpha = 0
        addSubview(imageView!)
    }

    func dropAnnotation() {
        let dropHeight:CGFloat = self.bounds.size.height - animatedView.frame.size.height
        let endPosition = CGPoint(x: animatedView.center.x, y: animatedView.center.y + dropHeight)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration, animations: {
             self.animatedView.alpha = 1
             self.animatedView.center = endPosition
        })
    }
}
```

---

**7) USAGE** in your `viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?` method, instantiate an `AnimatedAnnotation` and return that in the method.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    let bundle = Bundle.main // or your framework bundle
    let xib = UINib(nibName: "AnimatedAnnotation", bundle: bundle)
    let view = xib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! AnimatedAnnotation
    view.configureWith(animationDuration: 0.25, annotationImage: UIImage(named: "Your-Annotation-Image")
    return view
}
```

---

I haven't actually tried this in Xcode, and I just wrote this in the SO editor, but this should work. Let me know your progress.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this and let you know

Comment: @Shekar what was your experience with my solution?